# E-Commerce Shopping Cart Tshirt Builder (filter system)

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I'm creating a tshirt website and I need to be able to have a step by step process (page by page) in filtering out what tshirt is best for you with **wp-eCommerce**.

**this is how it need to be laid out:**
step one choose what collar type you want your shirt to have once selected -> next
step two choose what cufflink type you want your shirt to have once selected -> next
filter results based on category and or tags of the tshirt and only display what is requested by the tshirt builder selections.

**my question is how do I accomplish this in php or a pre-made script?**
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There won't be a pre built script

2) You can do it in php but you are going to have to take a look at how wp eCommerce stores it's data, depending on the database structure you may be able to filter data

3) You might wanna use some sort of tag system to help filter the shirts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you expect a reasonable answer to this question as it stands.  How are you storing tshirt data?  How are you managing sessions?  What are you really asking??? I mean, on the face of it, the architectural answer is pretty easy.  At each stage of the selection process, accumulate the users' selected filter for this stage in an array in the session variable or in the query string (&collar_type=turnover&cufflink=double_faced&tags[1]=humor&tags[2]=carlan).  Then, on each post, use the accumulated collection of filters to generate a new query against your tshirts data to populate the results to display on the next page.

With the information given, I don't know how a better answer can be provided.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Sorry, I forgot to include - I'm using wp-eCommerce.